# Python round function not working as expected

Tags: python

In Python, round(0.625) returns 0.62. why is this?
The following code only applies for positive numbers, what are better alternative?

```
from maths import floor
def round2Dp(n, decimals=0):
    multiplier = 10 ** decimals
    return floor(n*multiplier+0.5) / multiplier
```

Comment: Try ```round(0.625,3)```

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for numeric types [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex). Specifically:

> round(x[, n]): x rounded to n digits, rounding half to even. If n is omitted, it defaults to 0.

This basically means that half (0.5) is always rounded to the nearest *even* number.

Answer (score 0):

GeeksForGooks.com says, "When the second parameter is present, then it returns:
The last decimal digit till which it is rounded is increased by 1 when (ndigit+1)th digit is >=5 , else it stays the same."

Somebody tried to reject this answer, saying that he was pretty sure that was not what the web site said.  This was a direct cut and paste from this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/round-function-python/